# How to get Microsoft SQL MATH POWER to show as decimal and not as INT (which it seems to do)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have this simple query:

```
    SELECT POWER(( 1 + 3 / 100 ), ( 1 / 365 ))
```

According to MS SQL POWER(( 1 + 3 / 100 ), ( 1 / 365 )) = 1 when in fact it's 1,000080986

How to get Power to return Decimal instead of int. This topic seems similar to [Raising a decimal to a power of decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429165/raising-a-decimal-to-a-power-of-decimal) but that one touches c# and i need SQL. If there's no other way i'll use c# way.

Edited post to just show the problem without any specific information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precision is lost because your input values are all integers.

Try

```
SELECT POWER(( 1.0 + 3.0 / 100.0 ), ( 1.0 / 365.0 ))
```

If this doesn't give sufficient precision, cast the inputs to `POWER` as floats:

```
SELECT POWER(( CAST(1.0 as float) + CAST(3.0 AS float) / 100.0 ), ( 1.0 / 365.0 ))
```

Comment: Thanks, precision is important so that's why I'm choosing your answer as accepted one.

Comment: @MadBoy: Precision with float...? Just cast to decimal (38, 19) or something

Comment: I should have been more precise. Precision up to 8 places is important, so i will be cutting out what float returned anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT POWER(( 1.0 + 3.0 / 100 ), ( 1.0 / 365 ))
```

An expression like this  `1 + 3 / 100` implicitly uses integer arithmetic, so 3 / 100 is zero, as the decimal part is truncated.

Comment: Thanks, works, but precision is important so I've used Ed's solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT POWER(( 1 + 3.0 / 100 ), ( 1 / 365.0 ))
```

The same would happen in ***any*** (mainstream) language. Simple operator precedence issue and integer arithmetic. Nothing else

- 1/365 = 0
- Anything to power zero = 1
- And the left hand side of 1 + 3 / 100 would also equal one

Comment: That is also incorrect; you are still doing integer arithmetic (and gettig truncation) when you do 3 / 100. Ah! you edited it!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: yes, / evaluated before +  Serves me right for rushing