# Is it possible to raise a Decimal to an integer power in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

I'm in .NET (C#), and I have a piece of code that basically does the following:

```
decimal value = decimal.Parse(s);
long result = (long)(value * 10000M);
```

However, I can't use `10000` directly since the number of decimal places is variable (in this case, it's stored as `4`). Is there a way I can use this `4` to get to `10000M`?

I was thinking on something like `Math.Pow`, but it doesn't seem to be available for decimal types. I was also thinking on a simple function that does multiplication in a loop, but if something already exists in the .NET framework, then I'd rather use that.

Comment: You can use `Math.Pow` and then case the result to `decimal`.

Comment: this isn't raising a number to a power

Comment: @Kevin, 10000 = 10^4.

Comment: but 10000 isn't a decimal

Comment: @decoherence, it doesn't exist in the .NET framework.

Comment: @Kevin, you're right. Maybe it's simpler than I thought initially

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez because even if it existed it wouldn't make sense http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425501/is-there-a-math-api-for-powdecimal-decimal

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple method to raise a decimal to a **non-negative** integer power.

```
public static decimal Pow( decimal x, int n )
{
    if( n < 0 )
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( "n" );
    }

    decimal result = 1;
    decimal multiplier = x;

    while( n > 0 )
    {
        if( ( n & 1 ) > 0 ) result *= multiplier;
        multiplier *= multiplier;
        n >>= 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to use Math.Pow because it uses a generic math equation, and so is often slower (unless you are using fractional exponents which it looks like you are not). Instead I would write an extension method like this:

```
public static long ToPower(this decimal val, int pow)
{
    decimal ret = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < pow; i++)
        ret *= val;
    return (long)ret;
}
```

Which can be called like:

```
myDecimal.ToPower(4);
```

**EDIT:** I just ran a test to validate times. It seems that Math.Pow is now faster than a basic loop for any integer power above 50. The times are minimal, but often times when I am doing power math, I am doing a lot of calculations.

If you are doing this calculation a few times, then there is no need to use anything but Math.Pow as the performance changes are minimal.

Comment: The question was about doing it with decimals.

Comment: I updated the code to use a decimal for the value. However, that was a rather trivial change. The code only shows taking a decimal to an integer power, and that seems to be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I didn't downvote. That was just my most reasonable guess as to the downvote.

Comment: I see. I wasn't upset, just confused really. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it to a decimal after raising it to the power.

```
decimal value = decimal.Parse(s);
int power = 4;
long result = (long)(value * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, power));
```