# convert (long mantissa) and (sbyte exponent) to decimal

Tags: c#, decimal, numeric-conversion

**upd** placed my version in the description at the end

I need to convert mantissa and exponent to decimal.
This is how I coded that:

```
// long field.Decimal.Mantissa
// sbyte field.Decimal.Exponent
decimal MDEntryPx = field.Decimal.Mantissa * (decimal)(Math.Pow(10, field.Decimal.Exponent));
```

`field.Decimal.Mantissa` is integer
but `Math.Pow(10, field.Decimal.Exponent)` is double so I afraid that I can lost precision when casting to decimal.

Should I write my own `Pow` function for `integer` types that will produce `decimal`?

What would you suggest? I care about perfomance as I call this functions dozen of thousands times per second! So ugly but fast solutions are highly desired!

And I care about precision as I'm working with money here.

This is what I've just coded, but probably someone can suggest something better:

```
class Util
{
    private static readonly decimal[] posPow10 = {
                                           1M,
                                           10M,
                                           100M,
                                           1000M,
                                           10000M,
                                           100000M,
                                           1000000M,
                                           10000000M,
                                           100000000M,
                                           1000000000M,
                                           10000000000M,
                                           100000000000M
                                       };

    private static readonly decimal[] negPow10 = {
                                           1M,
                                           0.1M,
                                           0.01M,
                                           0.001M,
                                           0.0001M,
                                           0.00001M,
                                           0.000001M,
                                           0.0000001M,
                                           0.00000001M,
                                           0.000000001M,
                                           0.0000000001M,
                                           0.00000000001M,
                                       };


    public static decimal Pow(decimal mantissa, sbyte exponent)
    {
        decimal result = mantissa;
        if (exponent >= 0)
        {
            result *= posPow10[exponent];
        } else {
            result *= negPow10[-exponent];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429165/raising-a-decimal-to-a-power-of-decimal) and especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5425527/452274)?

Comment: @Matt Yes I did, It seems it will not work for negative integer exponents... however it's easy to modify to support negative exponent. but note my question is much easier. I don't need to raise decimal in power of decimal. I need to raise long in power of sbyte! So I work with integers. And I expect that probably some simple solution exist (probably using low-level instructions like << or something else....)

Answer (score 1):

There is [a constructor of `decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb1c1a6x.aspx) that does pretty much what you want. But it uses the internal representation of `decimal`, which is different from your representation. The conversion should be pretty simple for numbers with negative `exponent`, since you can directly translate that into the `scale` parameter of the constructor. But with positive `exponent`, I think you will need to do the multiplication by yourself.

Although I have no idea whether it would be actually faster than your code. And it would be certainly much less readable, so your solution might be fine.

Comment: i think my example from description would be more intuitive and probably even a little bit faster.

Comment: You're saying you care about performance. In that case, you should profile various versions of your code, not just guess.

Comment: I don't care that much. I prefer to have perfomance when it easy. I will profile only when perfomance problem would be obvious or I will have too much free time :)