# how to split decimal to long mantissa and sbyte exponent? or how to read c# decimal in c++?

Tags: c#

This question is opposite to my another [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993417/convert-long-mantissa-and-sbyte-exponent-to-decimal) question. I need to do opposite operation. I have c# decimal which I need to convert to this structure:

```
    public struct significand
    {
        public uint mantissa;  // or ulong
        public sbyte exponent;
    }
```

I pass this structure to c++ library via p/invoke later. How can I convert `decimal` to this structure? I guess probably I should use `Decimal.GetBits` method somehow? Or probably I can declare c++ structure some way so decimal will be automatically converted to it (i think they should be binary-compatible). Currently i'm using such c++ struct:

```
struct significand_t
{
uint32_t mantissa;
int8_t exponent;
};
```

Comment: Could you give a complete example?

Answer (score -1):

have a look here about [**Binary floating point and .NET**](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx)

you will find there a link to some sample code with will be useful for your case.

--r

Comment: Drilling down I did find the recommended link but it was dead, see the .zip links at the bottom of this useful article series: https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/mathematics/article.php/c9637/Floating-Point-in-NET-Part-I-Concepts-and-Formats.htm
I'll post an answer when I've got it all figured out.

Comment: if your're talking about this (http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) link, it's not dead and I have no idea how you're comment relates to my sort-of-answer (I know, I should have posted the link only as a comment myself instead of and answer)

Comment: I actually overlooked the sample code at the bottom of that link, I drilled down through to another link which brought me to an article, that article had a zip attached and that link was dead, but I found another article containing the same project files so I linked to that article.