# How do exponentiation algorithms work?

Tags: c, algorithm, function, math, exponentiation

Exponentiation in most modern languages is easy .. I use the common operator for that in my language of choice or whatever function that compensates that to get the desired functionality.
I want to know, how does this exactly work ?

The following algorithm in C is often used to demonstrate this effect ..

```
double exp(val, pow) {
    for(int i = 0; i < pow; ++i)
        val *= val;
    return val;
} // exp(2, 3) -> 8
```

However, there is a serious bug here .. What if *pow* is 2.6 ? That would return 8 also ..
That's simply because the loop condition only compares the two numbers ..
But when I do something like this, it works well ..

```
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    printf("The result of 2 to the power of 2.6 is %.2f", pow(2, 2.6));
}
```

How can the latter behavior be achieved ?

#### Edit:

According to the answers, it seems the taylor expansion algorithm is the key to exponentiation, so .. what about multiplication ? How can decimal multiplication be achieved ?

Comment: And thats not the only bug in this algorithm ...

Comment: http://www.quinapalus.com/efunc.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exponentiation is usually implemented as (lots of special cases plus) a reduction to exp. If you have an `exp` function and its inverse `ln` handy, you can compute x^y as

```
exp(y*ln(x))
```

But you might wonder how `exp` is implemented. For small arguments, the series expansion works well:

> exp(x) = 1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + x^4/24 + ...

Edit: This is the Taylor expansion referred to in the other answers.

For larger values there are argument reduction techniques that can be used to compute the value.

Comment: Certain platforms can take advantage of hardware as well. i.e. x86 can use the x87 FPU

Comment: AFAIK, `exp` (and some other transcendental functions)  is often computed using [chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials), not Taylor expensions. BTW, some compilers translate `exp` (on x86-64) to the hardware instruction computing it.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: Absolutely. I thought that would be out of scope of the answer, though.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yes, hardware instructions are almost always the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to accurately solve this problem but it is possible to approximate with a series as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429165/raising-a-decimal-to-a-power-of-decimal).

Comment: Please try and avoid link-only answers. Include the relevant information here, as links have a tendency to change.

Comment: @MikePrecup the link is to a StackOverflow answer - those kind of "internal links" seldom change in my experience.

Comment: @MortenJensen My bad, I hit the wrong macro, meant to use the internal links one. Link only answers are still considered bad, though, according to site standards, when no other information is provided.

Comment: @MikePrecup I disagree with you in that the solution is complex enough that we should strive to keep them in a community wiki or something. Trig approximations in C are notoriously difficult (and bug prone!) to write yourself :)

Comment: @MortenJensen Hm, the community wiki is an interesting point. Fair enough about the difficulty, shall we delete this conversation in a few minutes to remove some noise from the page?